# XmlReader.create() return none after second time

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader

I got a strange situation when I call a function and pass her a `Stream` object for the use of an creation `XmlReader` object.

First time this function works well, but if I call her another time and give her the same stream later on code, I got some exception that is an outcome of that `XmlReader.create()` return None instead of getting an allocation of an `XmlReader` object again, why is that?
What can I do?

Comment: Post your code, it'll make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Okay couple of minutes please, its pretty long will try to cut  non relevant sections

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be that you need to reset the position between reads if you are reading the same stream twice:

```
streamInstance.Position = 0;
```

Comment: just because Stream.position =0;
I thought the reset occur automatically

Comment: @JavaSa: why would it happen automatically? What if you didn't want the position to be reset?